# Why ffmpeg dcp playback behaving a different ways in mac and ubantu

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a Mac desktop and a Linux Ubuntu setup. I have installed source code of ffmpeg with x264 and Libopenjpeg support in Linux. On the other hand I have installed homebrew version of ffmpeg with libx264 and Libopenjpeg support on Mac OS. The following command automatically convert xyz colours pace to rgb in Linux, but dose not convert colourspace in Mac OS when I play dcp with ffmpeg. What is the reason behind this strange behavior??? My code is:

```
$ffmpeg -lowres 2 -ss 0 -r24 -i MOVIE.mxf -ss 0 -i AUDIO.mxf -ac: 2 -c:v libx264 -f matroska - | ffplay -
```

Comment: Please paste complete console output for both the mac and ubuntu command executions.